# Custom Login/Registration for Tenant Application in a sass

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, saas, laravel-filament, tenancyforlaravel

I want to make a saas application in which users can create a tenant and those tenants can have their own registration and login such that it looks like my saas application and the tenant application are not related.

Can this be achieved using [Multitenancy in Filament](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/tenancy) or [tenancy for laravel](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/introduction) package? Considering i want to use Filament as my admin panel but i want to use custom domains that are available in tenancy for laravel package. Any other package/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You need to try it by yourself and return with SPECIFIC question, if he will.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both tools together without any problems. There are projects on Github that help you start a project using the two packages in question.

You can see this here: [Filament Tenancy Starter](https://github.com/savannabits/filament-tenancy-starter)